# Return data from data-bind=text in html to python functions using KnockoutJS and Flask

Tags: javascript, python, knockout.js, flask

I'm using KnockoutJS along with Flask. I'm trying to get the data from data-bind="text: radioFrom" in my HTML file to be able to use in my python file, such as printing it out using a function, such as my function "func". The data-bind=text pulls data from a radio button.

Ultimately, I'm trying to send this data to a server.

I have attempted to get the data below (tab_id), but can't quite figure it out.
When I run my program locally, it gives me this error "BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'tab'. Did you forget to specify values ['tab_id']?"

Any ideas are appreciated.
Also, do I need to use jQuery for this, or can I do it without?

**In my python file...**

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/tabpanel')
def tabpanel():
    return render_template('tabpanel.html')

@app.route("/tabpanel/<int:tab_id>/")
def tab(tab_id):
    return render_template("tabpanel.html", tab_id) 

def func():
    print(tab_id)
    return
```

**The data to be pulled...**

```
<button id="myBtn">Verify...</button>

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h2>Please Verify Results.</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td class="label">From:</td>
                    <a data-bind="attr: { href: '{{ url_for('tab') }}' + '/' + id() }">
                        <td data-bind="text: radioFrom"></td>
                    </a>
                </tr>
            </table>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer" style="text-align:center">
            <span class="close"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**The radio button...**

```
<td class="label">From:</td>
    <td>
        <label><input type="radio" value="radio1" data-bind="checked: radioFrom" />radioname</label>
    </td>
```

**Knockout Code**

```
<script>
    var TabViewModel = function(){
        var self = this;
        var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

        var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

        var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

        btn.onclick = function() {
            modal.style.display = "block";
        }

        span.onclick = function() {
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }

        window.onclick = function(event) {
            if (event.target == modal) {
                modal.style.display = "none";
            }
        }

        self.radioFrom = ko.observable("radio1");
    };
    ko.applyBindings(new TabViewModel());
</script>
```

Comment: Please show your knockout VM

Comment: Is that what you were asking for?

Comment: I am not sure why don't you use `knockout binding` while you are using it .inside your model you subscribe to that element you need to get after change  `self.radioFrom.subscribe(function (newValue) {
        //console.log(newValue);
    }, self); `

Comment: @Matt.jaaj. Are you saying to replace `self.radioFrom = ko.observable("radio1");` with `self.radioFrom.subscribe(function (newValue) { console.log(newValue); }, self);`?

If so, that breaks my program. Can you elaborate?

Comment: No you need to define an observable variable then you can subscribe to that. Look at this example https://jsfiddle.net/kyr6w2x3/8/ also read http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html